# How to retain local UI state when using $resources with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

My problem is part of a [larger program](https://github.com/nurpax/hstodo/blob/master/static/todo.js) but I extracted a simulation of the problem in a simpler [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nurpax/Zk4NN/).

I'm implementing a "detailed view" show/hide controller for a todo item.  When I click on the link, a detailed view is shown or hidden.  The detailed view state is stored in `todo.showDetails`.  This works fine.

When I mark a todo as completed, I persist its current state on the server using:

```
// Persist immediately as clicked on
$scope.checkTodo = function (todo) {
    todo.$save();
};
```

This causes my detailed view to go hidden as the `todo.showDetails` state is lost because it's not part of the persisted item (i.e., it's overridden with the server's view of the todo item, which doesn't contain the UI state `todo.showDetails`).  I'm not surprised, this makes sense.

My question is: how can my todo items contain both local UI state and data that's persisted on the server?  When I `todo.$save()`, I'd like the `todo`'s data to be saved on the server *while* retaining the value of `todo.showDetails` in the client code.  I.e., whenever I call `todo.$save()`, I'd like my UI state to remain unchanged.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in AngularJS?  I wouldn't want to persist UI values like `showDetails` on the server.

One way I've been thinking of implementing this would be to have a separate service that stores UI state for each todo item.  When I need to access local state, instead of accessing like `todo.showDetails`, I could do something like `AppState.lookup(todo.id).showDetails` or similar.  But perhaps there's a simpler way..

-- **UPDATE 2013-02-25** --

I did as in the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15056593/45461) and simply separated UI state from todo items created by $resource.get/query calls.  It was a lot simpler than I thought (see [commit](https://github.com/nurpax/hstodo/commit/687e675a73b8df68f0c030d6d66ddefd3805174e)):

My controller changes:

```
     $scope.todos = Todo.query();
+    $scope.todoShowDetails = [];

+    $scope.toggleShowDetails = function (todo) {
+        $scope.todoShowDetails[todo.id] = !$scope.todoShowDetails[todo.id];
+    }
+
+    $scope.showDetails = function (todo) {
+        return $scope.todoShowDetails[todo.id];
+    }
```

Template changes:

```
-      <label class="btn btn-link done-{{todo.done}}" ng-click="todo.showDetails = !todo.showDetails">
+      <label class="btn btn-link done-{{todo.done}}" ng-click="toggleShowDetails(todo)">
..
-      <div ng-show="todo.showDetails" ng-controller="TodoItemCtrl">
+      <div ng-show="showDetails(todo)" ng-controller="TodoItemCtrl">
```

It's simple when I put it in code.  My jsfiddle example is a little bit contrived, it makes more sense in the context of my todo app.  Perhaps I should just delete the question if it's either difficult to understand or too trivial?

Comment: You could always use the plain $http module (maybe wrap it in your own directive) instead of the $resources..

Comment: really not clear what your issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to extract that UI state from your todo object? You'd still place the state object on the scope, just not inside the todo object. It sounds like that type of state doesn't belong in the todo object anyway, since you don't want to persist it.

Comment: If it was just a single item like in my fiddle, then yes, I'd definitely have it in my controller scope. In my app it's an array of todo items that I query from the server. Seems like I'll need to store UI state in a separate array then.

Comment: I did exactly that.  Thanks!